# React Router - Problems to render components. white screen

Tags: reactjs, navigation, react-router

I'm working in a dashboard with react a react-router-dom. I have a structure that is the Auth pages and dashboard pages. When I navigate from login to mainPages and try to select a navlink in the DashboardContainer show me a white screen.

```
const MainContainer  = ()=>{
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div style={{flexDirection: 'row', display: 'flex'}}>
                <Route path="/login" exact component={LoginPage}/>
                <Route path="/main" exact component={DashBoardCotainer}/>

            </div>


        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default MainContainer;
```

click on login button and redirect me to the dashboard

```
const LoginPage  = (props)=>{
    return(
        <div style={{width: '100%', height: '100vh', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
            <h1>Vendedor Solar</h1>
            <button onClick={()=>{props.history.push( '/main' )}}>Logar</button>


        </div>
    )
}

export default LoginPage;
```

the problem occurs when I click in a navlink of the side bar of dashboard

```
const DashBoardCotainer = () => {
    return (

        <div style={{flexDirection: 'row', display: 'flex'}}>
            <Navigation/>
            <div style={{padding: 20}}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/home" exact component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/order" exact component={Orders}/>
                    <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact}/>
                    <Route component={Error}/>
                </Switch>
            </div>

        </div>



    )
}

export default DashBoardCotainer;


class Navigation extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            navVisilbe:false
        }
    }

    render(){
        const {navVisilbe} = this.state

        return(
            <div style={{display:'flex', flexDirection: 'column', padding: 20, height: '100vh',
                backgroundColor: mainOrange}}>


                <NavLink to="/home"  exact

                        >Home</NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/order"  exact
                      >Pedidos</NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/contact"  exact

                         >Contatos</NavLink>


            </div>
        )
    }

}
export default Navigation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create one only file for route, where you can create 'Public' and 'Private' Layout like this

```
class MainContainer extends React.Component {
        render() {
        return(
            <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch> 
                <PublicLayout path="/login" exact component={LoginPage} />

                <PrivateLayout path="/home" exact component={Home} />
                <PrivateLayout path="/order" exact component={Order} />
                <PrivateLayout path="/contact" exact component={Contact} />
                // remove the 'exact' from route and you can make the nested routing working perfectly.. below example
                <PrivateLayout path="/contact/create" component={AddContact} />
            </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

export default MainContainer;
```

public layout

```
export const PublicLayout = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {  
    return <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          {<Component {...props} />} 
        </React.Fragment>  
    )} />
};
```

private layout

```
export const PrivateLayout = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {  

    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");   

    return <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className="sideBar"><Navigation /></div>
            <div className="contentBar">
                {!token ? <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location }}} /> : <Component {...props} /> }  
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>  
    )} />
};
```

your Navigation sideBar

```
export class Navigation extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            navVisilbe:false
        }
    }

    render(){
        const {navVisilbe} = this.state

        return(
            <div style={{display:'flex', flexDirection: 'column', padding: 20, height: '100vh', backgroundColor: mainOrange}}>

                <NavLink to="/home"  exact  >Home</NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/order"  exact >Pedidos</NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/contact"  exact  >Contatos</NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/contact/create"  exact  >Edit Contatos</NavLink>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Hope this would help :)

Comment: that solve a problem but im still with problems in nested routes. In the Contact screen if i click in contact/create link gives me a white screen again. 

 <div>

            <Link to={'/contact'}> <h1>Lista de usuários</h1></Link>
            <Link to={'/contact/create'}> <h1>Criar Uusário</h1></Link>

            <Route path={'/contact'} exact component={ListContact}/>
            <Route path={'/contact/create'} exact component={CreateContact}/>

        </div>

Comment: @TiagoPalmas I have modified above so you could fix you nested route problem.. please note that i have created 2 route for '/contact' and '/contact/create' but in nested i've remove the phrase 'exact'... :)

Comment: Thank you so  much !! do you know how can i connect the private layout to auth reducer to check authentication instead use localstorage?

Answer (score 1):

All of those routes are nested are `/main` so you need to update the links appropriately.

More details on nested routes: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start/example-nested-routing

```
const MainContainer = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div style={{ flexDirection: "row", display: "flex" }}>
        <Route path="/login" exact component={LoginPage} />
        <Route path="/main" component={DashBoardCotainer} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

const LoginPage = props => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        height: "100vh",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column"
      }}
    >
      <h1>Vendedor Solar</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          props.history.push("/main");
        }}
      >
        Logar
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const DashBoardCotainer = ({ match }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ flexDirection: "row", display: "flex" }}>
      <Navigation />
      <div style={{ padding: 20 }}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path={`${match.url}/home`} exact component={() => "Home"} />
          <Route path={`${match.url}/order`} exact component={() => "Orders"} />
          <Route
            path={`${match.url}/contact`}
            exact
            component={() => "Contact"}
          />
          <Route component={() => "error"} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

class Navigation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      navVisilbe: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { navVisilbe } = this.state;

    return (
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          padding: 20,
          height: "100vh"
        }}
      >
        <NavLink to="/main/home" exact>
          Home
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/main/order" exact>
          Pedidos
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/main/contact" exact>
          Contatos
        </NavLink>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MainContainer />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace all the routes in the parent Component in Where you call the dahboard component.

```
const MainContainer  = ()=>{
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div style={{flexDirection: 'row', display: 'flex'}}>
                <Route path="/login" exact component={LoginPage}/>
                <Route path="/main" exact component={DashBoardCotainer}/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/home" exact component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/order" exact component={Orders}/>
                    <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact}/>
                    <Route component={Error}/>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default MainContainer;
```